# How do we promote the site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There is a flood of doubts and articles all over the internet (Quora accounts for a significant amount of such questions) about data science.

But, very few of them know about the existence of the Data Science SE, which is a much more professional and dedicated site for addressing such doubts. So, how can the site be promoted and make it's value known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site would probably get more attention if people actually voted on questions and answers, and also accepted answers.  There are so many questions with multiple good answers where no one votes on the question or the answers.  Reputation is a part of what drives people to answer. Without encouraging voting and accepting answers this site will  have a hard time growing.

Comment: Definitely agree with you.  The _Vote early, vote often_ principle should definitely be applied here.   It was worse for some time, but I can see it getting better recently.  :)

Answer (score -1):

One of the pretty obvious solutions is to actively promote Data Science SE site by mentioning it on relevant web sites, blogs, etc. Specifically, on Quora, you can mention this site in your answers as well as linking to relevant questions or answers here.

Having said that, while DS SE is a dedicated data science site, unfortunately I have to disagree that it is more professional (which should be the case, in theory), as I see a large number of high quality questions, answers and posts on Quora in relevant categories.

Quora has its own share of problems, discussing which is beyond the scope of this answer (and I don't have time for that, anyway), however, many experienced data scientists are active on Quora and likely don't see reasons to split their activities between it and DS SE. It is a problem for this site and I don't have a perfect solution for that.

As for "flood of doubts and articles ... about data science", promoting this site IMHO will not change that at all. This is because all those "doubts and articles" are less of factual nature and more of opinions and discussions nature, which, by design, clearly represent a better fit for sites, such as Quora, forums, blogs, etc., rather than more factual-based sites, such as Data Science SE.